# How to transform UIBezierPath with UITouch

Tags: ios, swift, uibezierpath, uitouch

i am trying to change the shape of UIBezierPath that i have created like in this tutorial:
[https://www.appcoda.com/bezier-paths-introduction/]
thats my code:

```
class Geometry: UIView {

    //var path: UIBezierPath!
    var path = UIBezierPath()

    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        createLine(x: 100, y: 100)
    }
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame: frame)

        self.backgroundColor = UIColor.white
    }

    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        super.init(coder: aDecoder)
    }
    func transformShape(x:CGFloat, y:CGFloat)
    {
        path.removeAllPoints()
        createLine(x: x, y: y)
    }
    func createLine(x: CGFloat, y: CGFloat)
    {
        var path = UIBezierPath()
        path.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0.0, y: 0.0))
        path.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))
        path.close()
        path.fill()
        path.stroke()
    }

    override func touchesBegan(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        let touch = touches.first
        let location = (touch?.location(in: self))!;
        transformShape(x:location.x, y:location.y)
    }
    override func touchesMoved(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        let touch = touches.first
        let location = (touch?.location(in: self))!;
        transformShape(x:location.x, y:location.y)
    }
    override func touchesEnded(_ touches: Set<UITouch>, with event: UIEvent?)
    {
        let touch = touches.first
        let location = (touch?.location(in: self))!;
        transformShape(x:location.x, y:location.y)
    }
}
```

i have added the the view in the viewcontroller like this:

```
import UIKit

var geo = Geometry()

let screenWidth: Int = 1024
let screenHeight: Int = 768

class ViewController: UIViewController {

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        geo = Geometry(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: screenWidth, height: screenHeight))
        self.view.addSubview(geo)

    }
}
```

to make it easier to understand what i want to do i made this. i want to be able to move the end of both lines to the left and right on x without changing the y-postion

[image]

i have not found anything besides animation. but thats not what i want to accomplish. the top of the triangle should follow the movements of the finger. thanks

Comment: Pretty simple: as the finger moves, redraw the path, with the line `addLine(to: CGPoint(x: x, y: y))` changing to the point where the finger is now.

Comment: @matt when i do that i get this error: [Unknown process name] CGContextSetFillColorWithColor: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

Comment: i am pretty sure that i should remove the line before i re-add it agai. but i get the same error then

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It certainly isn't difficult to do this in a crude way:

[image]

Here's how I'm doing that:

```
class MyView : UIView {
    override init(frame: CGRect) {
        super.init(frame:frame)
        backgroundColor = .yellow
        let g = UIPanGestureRecognizer(target: self, action: #selector(pan))
        self.addGestureRecognizer(g)
    }
    @objc
    func pan(_ g:UIGestureRecognizer) {
        switch g.state {
        case .changed:
            let p = g.location(in: self)
            self.apex.x = p.x
            self.setNeedsDisplay()
        default: break
        }
    }
    required init?(coder aDecoder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }
    lazy var apex = CGPoint(x:self.bounds.midX, y:self.bounds.midY)
    override func draw(_ rect: CGRect) {
        let con = UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()!
        con.move(to: CGPoint(x: 0, y: self.bounds.maxY))
        con.addLine(to: self.apex)
        con.addLine(to: CGPoint(x: self.bounds.maxX, y: self.bounds.maxY))
        con.strokePath()
    }
}
```

In that code, I'm simply setting the apex point to where the finger is (keeping the y-component constant, as you specify), and redrawing the whole bezier path. So everything from there is just a question of refinement — reducing latency, for example (which you can do by anticipating touches).

Comment: i understand which point i have to change. but what ever i do the app is crashing with this error: [Unknown process name] CGContextSetFlatness: invalid context 0x0. If you want to see the backtrace, please set CG_CONTEXT_SHOW_BACKTRACE environmental variable.

Comment: i also have set the variable global and removed the path completly and called the function again: path.removeAllPoints()
        createLine(x: x, y: y)

Comment: I can't see what you're doing; only you can see your code. I'm trying to give you some idea of how to do it; how _not_ to do it is not interesting. Clearly you are trying to manipulate a graphics context at a time when there _is_ no graphics context. I'm doing it all in the view's `draw(_:)`, where there is a graphics context.

Comment: Yup, well, it's just what I said. The only place it is legal to call `createLine` is from within `draw(_:)`. So it works when you do that and doesn't when you call it from all those other places. The apex point needs to be an instance property that `createLine` can look at _from within `draw(_:)`_.

Comment: Right, don’t copy my code, just use it to show the sort of structure you’d need in your own code.

Comment: yeah. i have tried it and it works. no idea whats going on in there yet. i always try to write it from scratch so i can understand later if problems show up. thanks